# Solr boosting based on field value

Tags: search, solr, lucene

By the looks of it I have a few options with regards to boosting. I was wondering from a performance point of view am I better to set the boost of certain results on import via the DIH or instead is it better to set the boost when doing queries, by adding it to the default queries?

I have a "source" value and I want to boost it in the relevancy if it has a certain value, say for example:

```
source=google then boost 10 
source=bing then boost 5
```

Thanks for any help you can give!

James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your Source is fixed, you can use index time boost which will be faster then the query time boost.
Any change in the boost however, would require the Complete reindexing of data.
Using a Query time would help changing the boost dynamically, providing a greater control over the results.
Query time boosts can be changed without the need to reindex the data again and would take effect with a simple reloading of the Cores.